Blazor Auto RenderRing (InteractiveServer and InteractiveWasm)
I pass a long time with blazor server it was perfectly for some type of projects.
and now i'm trying to migrate my project to Blazor Auto App (InteractiveServer et InteractiveWebAssembly ) with dotnet 8 it create by default Client Project and Client Project and when i add Component in Server Project and when i go to that route it return **Not Found**
can you any one explain me what's the problem
When i add component in web assembly it work perfectly and also when i a make modeRendering as null it work also

You need to provide more details. Your page? Is the route there? What do your program.cs files look like?   Did you use the template what dis you set... You can't ask questions and expect help without the information...

This component or page you write in server project. It must be write in client project.
Component or page in server project cant using interactive auto
